# How to modify protractor html screenshot reporter to show report for each "expect" (assertion ) instead of each "it" block in spec file.

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Suppose My test is like this :

it('should have a history', function() {

add(1, 2);

expect(history.count()).toEqual(3);// A

add(5, 6);

expect(history.count()).toEqual(0); // B

});

If B fails whole of spec is shown as failed in the protractor html screenshot report. 
I want the Html Reporter to show the report at expect level instead of "It" level, i.e Along with showing that spec failed, it should show which assertion within that spec passed and which assertion failed.

some thing like this:

Should have history : Failed

A -> Passed

B-> Failed

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify protractor html screenshot reporter to show report for each “expect” (assertion ) instead of each “it” block in spec file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383277/how-to-modify-protractor-html-screenshot-reporter-to-show-report-for-each-expec)