# How to modify protractor html screenshot reporter to show report for each “expect” (assertion ) instead of each “it” block in spec file

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I have 3 'it' specs with 27 expects in the code. protractor-html-screenshot-reporter includes 'it' specs but not expect level results.

Please let me know, can i make any configuration changes to make it work.

Thanks,
Arpit Jain

Answer (score 1):

`protractor-html-screenshot-reporter` **works on the spec-level** (`it` blocks).

According to the [source code](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/index.js), it defines the [`reportSpecResults` function](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter/blob/master/index.js#L131) which is called by jasmine when the reporting results for a spec run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please let me know, what could be the solution, if I want expect level results in my report?

Answer (score 0):

The below code takes a screenshot on each Failed expect:

```
// takes screenshot on each failed expect
var originalAddMatcherResult = jasmine.Spec.prototype.addMatcherResult;
jasmine.Spec.prototype.addMatcherResult = function() {
++index;
if (!arguments[0].passed()) {
  screenshot(this.description, index);
}
return originalAddMatcherResult.apply(this, arguments);
```

};

Hope this helps!